# What could be wrong? My front door latch opens OK from inside, poorly from outside

Tags: doors, lock, front-door, latches

The following Kwikset lockset on my front door no longer works well.  From the inside rotating handle it's fine.  From the outside it's sticky, as the bolt does not fully pull in.  This particular lockset replaced an older and more sturdier model a few years back.  Nothing inside seems amiss.   I've checked the backset and it seems fine.

[image: Kwikset Hawthorne Single Cylinder Sectional Handleset failure]

[image: Kwikset Hawthorne Single Cylinder Sectional Handleset core]

Comment: I have seen trouble like you are having with that type of leverset. It may take a simple touch of grease on the right places, sometimes the alignment is just not so so right. They can be finicky. Just  thought, can the thumb press move in and out? It appears the lever that works off the outside thumb press is restricted to a degree.

Comment: Honest question, @Jack. Grease or some sort of dry lube like graphite or a silicone spray? Seems that inside the door, grease would be reasonably well protected from collecting dirt/dust, but could still get gummed up over time.

Comment: Those alternatives will as well. In the matter of grease, I don't know what particular "blend" may gum up over time, since there are a few formulas out there. I am guessing old fashioned moly, I think it is called. I have disassembled really old rim locks and mortice locks, the grease still doing as it should. I am leaning towards it being more of an alignment/leverage thing rather than lube. Although that should be done periodically anyway.

Comment: Rereading the question, this lock has been installed for a few years now, and now is acting badly. It may be a lube issue after all or a wear issue, which may be possible in a cheaper handle set. Something has happened to the inside of the hardware that changes the up and down motion, to a rotating motion to actuate the latchbolt.

Comment: could be related to temp, metal shrinking just enough to be a problem.

Comment: I added lubricant, that just make it work more smoothly.  The same problem exists.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem turned out to be wear.  The exterior latch turns a half circle piece of metal, which bears on the latch.  Metal on metal, one with a sharp edge?  No wonder it wore out:

[image: Kwikset worn out poor design]

The upper bearing surface is the factory shape, the lower shows the wear.

The interior handle actuator bears slightly higher and apparently wore more slowly.

Kwikset apparently has a ***lifetime warranty*** on mechanical and finish issues.  I called them and they readily agreed to send out a new part at no charge with no receipt.

That said, bad design good warranty is an unfortunate policy: the new part will clearly wear out in the same way next time.  I will lubricate it, but lubricant only goes so far.

In the interim a paperclip is doing the trick:
[image]

Comment: Excellent find! I'm glad you got this sorted and that Kwikset is honoring their warranty. I agree with the somewhat questionable design, however, I've got to wonder just how old this one is - you say "a few years back"... Our front door knob (not sure if it's a Kiwkset) is nearly 30 yo. It's got a wobble, but the knob turns just fine, and I'd imagine the setup is fairly similar. (Now you've got me motivated to take it apart once the weather warms up - maybe it is wearing and I can get some replacement parts!)